# Iterate through hasMany / belongsTo relation in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I want to return the child elements (notes) of a given draft (parent element) as a computed property from my `Ember.DocumentController`.
In this case I want to return all the notes that belong to the `editableDraft` property.

Or is there a better way of doing it?

```
App.DocumentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  editableDraft: function() {
    var editDrafts = this.get('model.drafts').filterBy("editable", true);
    var draft = editDrafts.length ? editDrafts[0] : null;
    return draft;
  }.property('model.drafts.@each.editable'),
  editableNotes: function() {
    var eDraft = this.get("editableDraft"); // want to return notes of editableDraft
    return eDraft.get("notes");
  }.property('model.drafts.@each.editable')
});
```

See test app in the [jsbin!](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qajecivo/17/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: What are you having trouble with? What is not working?

Comment: I can't get the notes to render for `editableDraft`. If you click the link "Gregor Samsa & the Bug" it should render the notes below the text. Right now it returns the else condition: "No notes yet..." though the draft has notes in the fixtures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems. One, in the `document` template, here:

```
{{render 'editableDraftNotes' notes}}
```

Render does some weird thing with replacing your controller and model with the provided arguments. Not what you need in this case. Try this:

```
{{partial 'editableDraftNotes'}}
```

Two, in the `editableNotes` property. You should listen to changes on `editableDraft`. Also, because Ember.Data returns promises, you must chain your gets (`this.get("A.B")` instead of `this.get("A").get("B")`). Try this:

```
  editableNotes: function() {
    return this.get("editableDraft.notes");
  }.property('editableDraft')
```

Working jsbin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qajecivo/31/edit).